# Linq query performance with Take filter

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there difference in performance of the following linq queries:

```
 var query = from q in this.context.SomeTable
            where q.SomeId == SomeId
            select new SomeViewModel
            {
                PrimaryAttr = q.PrimaryAttr;
                Attribute1 = q.Attribute1,
                Attribute2 = q.Attribute2,
                Attribute3 = q.Attribute3
            };

query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.PrimaryAttr).Take(5).ToList();
```

And if I filter in first the query in same line:

```
var query = (from q in this.context.SomeTable
            where q.SomeId == SomeId
            select new SomeViewModel
            {
                PrimaryAttr = q.PrimaryAttr;
                Attribute1 = q.Attribute1,
                Attribute2 = q.Attribute2,
                Attribute3 = q.Attribute3
            }).OrderByDescending(q => q.PrimaryAttr).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they are the same exact query.

Please note that the query is not executed until you execute the ToList method.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain most LINQ queries directly because most of them are executed delayed. The result of such an expression is kind of a query-plan which is executed not until you call `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Having said this your two queries are exactly the same.

For further information on this topic read [deferred execution and lazy evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)